# NameError: uninitialized constant User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, console

I am using the rails-devise apps with Rails composer. Everything seems fine until I try to interact with the model in the console.
I tried the commands:

```
rails console
User.all
```

And I get the following error from the console:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User
from (irb):2
from /Users/msarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/msarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/msarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/msarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/msarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/msarr/Desktop/deployment/YouServe/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/msarr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/msarr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  ruby '2.2.1'
  gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'turbolinks'
  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'carrierwave'
  gem 'mini_magick'
  gem 'fog'                  
  gem 'administrate'
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'devise_invitable'
  gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 5.5'
  gem 'high_voltage'
  gem 'simple_form'

 group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'hub', :require=>nil
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
 gem 'unicorn'
end
```

Comment: did you run ```rails generate devise User ; rake db:migrate``` ?

Comment: I tried and it says Could not find generator 'devise'

Comment: then you haven't included ```gem 'devise'``` in your gemfile and then run ```bundle```

Comment: Devise is actually included in the gem file. It ' s all weird. Authentication works and everything but just accessing the models in the console is the problem

Answer (score 10):

Just restarting the spring loader.

```
spring stop
```

then run `rails c` It's working fine

Comment: This works for me, but would be great to get more details or documentation on what is going on? Any long-term fix?

Comment: @Meekohi `spring` is a preloader. It's optional whether you want to use it, but it can speed up development. [see `rails/spring`](https://github.com/rails/spring)

Answer (score 1):

What does the architecture of your project look like? If you have any modules or namespacing wrapped around your models (`API` or `v1`, for example), then you would have to call them with the namespace, i.e. `V1::User.all`.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to include `gem 'devise'` in your Gemfile and run `bundle`

also you will need to run the following

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
rake db:migrate
```

Now you should be able to access `User.all` in your `rails c`

Comment: Devise is actually included in the gem file. It ' s all weird. Authentication works and everything but just accessing the models in the console is the problem. rails g devise User command  results in "Could not find generator 'devise'"

Comment: Do you have ```gem 'devise'``` behind ```group :production do``` or something in the gemfile? That's the only reason i can think of you not being able to use the generator in the console given that you say it is installed and working

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added my gem file . And when I execute bundle show devise, I get /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.6